# How to combine two different request for two different columns in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want a macro that automatically multiplies a given column by a set number. This number will be different for each column. I am only able to apply it to one column so far. I can't have it done for any other:

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Value = Target.Value * 300
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    


If Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Value = Target.Value * 500
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: How many columns? Posted an answer but there's probably a simpler way.

Comment: Hi @BigBen, im looking to have this done for five columns, B to F. I thought if i saw how to do it for more than one, I could do it for the rest. Could you show how it would be done for another row please? Let's say column D should be multpilied by 400

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B:B")

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Value = rng.Value * 300
    End If
    
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C:C"))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Value = rng.Value * 500
    End If

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**EDIT**:
This is probably a better approach if you have more than two columns (and they are contiguous):

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B:F")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo SafeExit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        Dim rng as Range
        For Each rng In Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B:F"))
            Dim multiplier As Long
            
            Select Case rng.Column
                Case 2 ' column B
                    multiplier = 300
                Case 3 ' column C
                    multiplier = 500
                Case 4 ' column D
                    multiplier = 400
                Case 5 ' column E
                    multiplier = ...
                Case 6 ' column F
                    multiplier = ...
            End Select

            If IsNumeric(rng.Value) Then
                rng.Value = rng.Value * multiplier
            End If   
        Next 
    End If

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: a syntax error pops up when i try to run the code https://ibb.co/wQVgW2t